# Quickest way to write to file in java

Tags: java, optimization, file-io, directory-structure

I'm writing an application which compares directory structure. First I wrote an application which writes gets info about files - one line about each file or directory.

Here is my solution which is calling a method `toFile()`

```
Static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("DirStructure.dlis")), true);
String line; // info about file or directory
public void toFile(String line) {
    pw.println(line);
}
```

and of course `pw.close()`, at the end.

My question is, can I do it quicker? What is the quickest way?

Edit:
The meaning of "quickest" way is fastest writing in the file

Comment: I assume you mean simpler or clearer instead of quicker.

Comment: You assume wrong, I meant really quicker. I need quick writing to that file, cause there will be a lot of files -> a lot of lines.

Comment: If you're having a lot of files to write, you may want to rethink your design - you'll be writing to the files longer than you'll be doing any significant data gathering.

Comment: Do you simply want a function that takes in a file and lines does the above operation accordingly?

Comment: @Makoto Did you read my question properly? I write to one file, each line that I write to this file is information about directory structure, if its directory line = just path+name|d, if its file line = path+name|f|size|MD5hash

Comment: The speed at which you can obtain the data is almost certainly going to be 100x slower so this is likely to be fine for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Peter Lawrey** wrote: 
The speed at which you can obtain the data is almost certainly going to be 100x slower so this is likely to be fine for writing. 
So it seems my solution which is showed in questions is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Sun actually has a [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/perftuning-137844.html) about this. According to them you can get up to 17 times the speed (in worst case to best case situations).

They speak about buffering, direct buffering, the OS and many more useful topics.
Considering, as you said, you will have lots of files and lines, I suggest stream compression/decompression as an approach, but do read the whole thing (I haven't and only answered from experience).

Edit:
Considering it's homework, knowledge of all the concepts in that page will certainly impress your teacher, so you might add a few comments saying what you're doing, and why, as well as list the alternatives. ;)

Edit 2:
Just saw exactly what the line contains. If the files will only contain that info, consider asynchronously creating the lines for the next files while they are in queue. That is to say the directory should be multiple directory names, combined properly etc etc. See [this section](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/#ObtainingFileInformation) of the link on fast operations to get info on the file.

Comment: Actually the OP is already using an intermediate buffer stream, the 17-fold speedup referred to a difference between unbuffered and self-implemented buffered. The speedup between `BufferedInputStream` and the self-implemented one was only almost double.

Comment: @trutheality I realize that, when I referenced the 17x I meant the maximal possible efficiency boost achieved in general, that is to say it will allow him to increase efficiency by 17x max between two situations. Edit the answer to make that more clear.